# Drawing points in layer given its coordinates using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, python-3, display, centroids

I want to draw points in a certain polygon layer. Specifically, I want to display the centroid over each respective feature. All this using PyQGIS.
So far, none of the answers I found helped me. I am using QGIS 3.10.

I am a newbie here. Should I create another layer? Should I edit the current layer? How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

No need for python. Copy-paste layer, Layer symbology - centroid fill:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the centroid as a new file, you can use centroid tool from `Processing toolbox -> Vector geometry -> Centroids` or from `Vector toolbar menu -> Geometry Tools -> Centroids`

[image]

Run the tool and your will get the centroid of each polygon

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can make it in one layer without any script and an additional layer for visualization purpose.

1. Open "Layer Styling" (F7)
2. Click plus button to add a new symbol layer

   [image]
3. Select the first symbol layer

   [image]
4. Set `Symbol layer type` to `Centroid Fill`

   [image]

   [image]

Result:

[image]